# Is an external identity provider needed to implement SAML SSO in a Javascript web app?

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

My question is that in order to allow customers to access a web app via SSO does the web app simply need to be able to consume a SAML response without the need for a dedicated identity provider and if so what is generally speaking the best direction for implementation?

This scenario assumes that the customers have their own own IdP solutions such as OneLogin or Active Directory or Azure AD. The goal is to allow the web app to be able to accept and utilize a SAML message to allow customer to add the application to their own app catalogs such as in Azure non-gallery apps or in their respective OneLogin portals.

Lastly, is it possible to implement SAML in the web app while keeping the existing user DB or will the DB need to migrated to a different solution ( Currently using salted hashes in a MongoDB ).?

Comment: SAML is *a* way to authenticate, but does not need to be the only way.  As an app utilizing another company's IdP, you only need to implement the SP (service provider) portion.  You don't need to also be an identity provider.

Comment: I can understand that, but do we need to setup our own IdP? In most SAML examples I have seen there is always in Identity Provider field but i haven't found any true clarification that as the SP we have to have an IdP solution such as OneLogin.

Comment: If you are a SAML SP, then there is a SAML IdP that you are talking to.  Usually, this is a customer's identity provider that they are using for their other identity needs.  SAML SP gets an authentication assertion from an IdP -- that's how federated login works.  You as the SP do not provide the IdP, but it is a necessary half for federated login to actually work.

Comment: Also in your solution you can keep users in the same collection/table but the hashes won't be used, since you aren't authenticating users with them.  You may be keeping other information about users (e.g. roles, attributes, etc.) that you still need in your application. We use a single collection for both local and federated users.

Comment: @DaltonSchwartzkopf You could use some free of charge SAML IdPs for testing, e.g https://www.ssocircle.com/en/samlopenid-idp/